# Django Form Wizard BooleanFields always returning False

Tags: python, django, forms, wizard

First of all, I am generically creating my form from the database. Here are my codes:

template:

```
{% block wizard_form_content %}
<div id="alt-list">
    <div id="alt-list-header">
        <h4>Grids List</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="alt-list-data" class="container">
    {% for grid in data.grids %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="{{ grid.name }}" id="id_{{ grid.name }}" tabindex="{{ forloop.counter}}" size="30">{{ grid.name }}<br>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% if wizard.form.errors %}
<div class="form-errors-wrapper">
    <div class="error">
    {% for error in wizard.form.non_field_errors %}
        <p>{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
<input type="hidden" name="num-grids" value="{{ data.grids|length }}" id="num-grids" />
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ data.user }}" id="user" />
{% endblock wizard_form_content %}
```

And this is the corresponding form:

```
class WhichGridsForm(forms.Form):
#     Override the initialize in order to dynamically add fields to the form in order to be saved,
#     the fields are saved only when the user selects 'Next Step'.
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(WhichGridsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if len(self.data) > 0:
            self.num_grids = self.data['num-grids']
            user_name = self.data['user']

            user1 = User.objects.filter(username=user_name)

            gridtype = Grid.GridType.USER_GRID
            templateData = ShowGridsData()
            templateData.grids = Grid.objects.filter(user=user1, grid_type=gridtype)

            for grid in templateData.grids:
                gridName = grid.name
                # Every time, alternative fields are added with the name 'alternative..', and this because django
                # always adds '1-' % (where 1 the number of the step with zero index) prefix in the name,
                # with this the names are kept always the same.
                self.fields[gridName] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Keeping in the mind that this is step 2, when I am trying to reach this step 2 data from step 3 with this line of code:

```
elif self.steps.step1 == 3:
            try:
                grids_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('1')
                print grids_data
```

All of the fields seems "False" even though I checked them all.

```
{u'Cars': False, u'grid11': False, u'deneme11': False, u'asd': False}
```

Do you have any idea why this would happen?

Edit:

But If I print the form fields in the 'done' method, I get the correct results:

```
<MultiValueDict: {u'num-grids': [u'4'], u'deneme11': [u'on'], u'Cars': [u'on'], u'composite_wizard-current_step': [u'1'], u'grid11': [u'on'], u'user': [u'muratayan'], u'asd': [u'on'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'JYIT5gHs35ZBvk7rCITfpMIPrFleUYXF']}>
```

Comment: use should use MultipleChoiceField instead..

Comment: now they are just empty, instead of False.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I gave you the wrong field class. Instead `MultipleChoiceField` it should be `ModelMultipleChoiceField`, since you select from models.

Something like this works in my case:

forms.py (form for first step)

```
class FirstStepForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FirstStepForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['countries'] = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Country.objects.all())
```

views.py

```
class MyWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def render(self, form=None, **kwargs):
        response = super(MyWizard, self).render(form, **kwargs)

        grids_data = self.get_cleaned_data_for_step('0') or {}
        print grids_data

        return response
```

Comment: I figured it out with some other way, that's why not giving you a check because I haven't try it but thank you so much.